# How to pass the configured passport object into the routes modules in Express4?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, express-4

Since from Express 4 you're not supposed to do

```
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

module.exports = function(app, passport) {
    // =====================================
    // FACEBOOK ROUTES =====================
    // =====================================
    // route for facebook authentication and login

    app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

    // handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
    app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
        passport.authenticate('facebook', {
            successRedirect : '/profile',
            failureRedirect : '/'
        }));

    // route for logging out
    app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });
};
```

Instead, you're supposed to be using `express.Route()` function and

```
var routes = require('./app/routes.js');
app.use('/', routes);
```

How to pass the configured passport into the routes modules in Express 4?

Answer (score 8):

The `function` export can still be used to pass the `passport` reference between modules. It would just create and `return` a `Router` rather than modifying the `app` directly.

```
var express = require('express');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    var router = express.Router();

    router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

    // etc.

    return router;
};
```

And, the `app` can then `use` it with:

```
var routes = require('./app/routes.js')(passport);
app.use('/', routes);
```

Comment: but when I tried the implementation above, I just got a new problem:        Cannot GET /auth/facebook/callback?code=************** and there is no error info.  How can I deal with this?

Comment: @bolerovt I snipped out some of the routes from my post to keep it short, replaced with `// etc.` Did you copy that line or do you have the `router` with `'/auth/facebook/callback'` and `'/logout'` routes?

Comment: I'm afraid yes.... Now I'm getting back to the original Error: read ETIMEDOUT... I have absolute no clue what's going on there... sorry man